# string variables not working on raspberry pi

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

I have been using string variables in my "controller" for my raspberry pi robot which change depending on a users arrow key inputs and when they change sends the information over a socket server. this program runs fine on my laptop and a basic server that prints the information received runs on my Raspberry Pi. I am now working on using this information to control motors etc. My issue is for some reason i can't get this to work.

```
import SocketServer
import Tkinter as Tk
from Tkinter import *

class MyTCPHandler (SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
        def handle(self):
              self.DriveSend = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
              self.SteeringSend = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
              print("{} wrote:".format(self.client_address[0]))
              print(self.DriveSend)
              print(self.SteeringSend)
              main.DriveVar.set(self.DriveSend)
              main.SteeringVar.set(self.SteeringSend)
              self.request.sendall(self.DriveSend.upper())
              self.request.sendall(self.SteeringSend.upper())
if __name__ == "__main__":
        HOST, PORT = "192.168.2.12", 9999
        server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler)
        server.serve_forever()
        DriveVar = StringVar()
        SteeringVar = StringVar()
```

Below is the exception/error that is produced.

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('192.168.2.10', 52447)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 284, in _handle_request_noblock
self.process_request(request, client_address)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 310, in process_request
self.finish_request(request, client_address)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 323, in finish_request
self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 638, in __init__
self.handle()
File "server.py", line 12, in handle
main.DriveVar.set(self.DriveSend)
NameError: global name 'main' is not defined
```

Why is this not working?
How do I fix it or what should I use instead (bearing in mind the variables are received in a function within a class called in by the Main

Comment: Where is your `main` defined? If it is a modul name, you should import it. If the `Main` is a class defined in some module, you have to prefix it with the module name. Also, Python is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually managed to get this to work but without string variables.

```
import SocketServer
import Tkinter as Tk
from Tkinter import *

class MyTCPHandler (SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
          self.DriveSend = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
          self.SteeringSend = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
          print("{} wrote:".format(self.client_address[0]))
          #print(self.DriveSend)
          #print(self.SteeringSend)
          self.request.sendall(self.DriveSend.upper())
          self.request.sendall(self.SteeringSend.upper())
          motorcontrol.self
          return(self.DriveSend,self.SteeringSend)

def motorcontrol(motor_var)
    motor = motor_var.DriveSend
    steering = motor_var.SteeringSend
if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "192.168.2.12", 9999
    server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler)
    server.serve_forever()
```